# Running 'chrome' code in SpiderMonkey

Tags: javascript, spidermonkey

I'm embedding Mozilla's SpiderMonkey in my application and would like to use its new 
[Debugger API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey/JS_Debugger_API_Guide) introduced in v1.8.6. From the documentation, I understand that this API is not available to 'content code' but only to trusted so-called 'chrome code'.
Now I have gone through a number of resources trying to understand how to execute 'chrome code', without much success. My guess is that the trusted script should be execute with JS_EvaluateScriptForPrincipals, but then I cannot understand how to use JSPrincipals...

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a SpiderMonkey engine embedding, there are no such concepts. The idea of "chrome" and "content" is only legitimate in the browser, where "chrome" is privileged (like the Firefox UI / addons) and "content" is untrusted (like a web page).

When you embed the JS engine you just have access to JavaScript, the language, with its typical built in classes and language features. When you build the shell and run it, you can just type "Debugger" and you'll see the debugger object is present. This happens whenever you create a new global in the SpiderMonkey engine.

```
$ ./js
js> Debugger
function Debugger() {[native code]}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback, it probably was too obvious for me to find out!

Comment: Digging deeper, I got SpiderMonkey's latest source code from Mozilla's Mercurial. From the shell (js), I can see the Debugger indeed, but when I embed a vanilla build of the lib, I can't see it. So I'm trying to find out how the shell does activate it, but all I see are calls to the JSD_ API which is, if I'm correct, the "old" debugger API... Any hint ?

Comment: ahem... that was JS_DefineDebuggerObject on the global, you can slap my face for asking too quickly.